# How to remove encoded characters when serializing an input array?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have my partial view which contains this:

```
<div class="multiplePaths">
  @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model[i].Label)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Path, new {@class = "form-control col-md-10"})
     </div>
  }
</div>
```

When I call this jQuery:

```
var model = $(".multiplePaths :input").serialize();
```

The results look something like this:

```
%5B0%5D.Label=Repertoire%20destination&%5B0%5D.Path=
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formatting is because `serialize()` is intended to output a querystring. As such, special characters, such as `[` and `]`, are URI encoded.

To get the output you want you simply need to URI decode them again:

```js
var model = $(".multiplePaths :input").serialize();
console.log('encoded:', model);

var decodedModel = decodeURI(model);
console.log('decoded:', decodedModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multiplePaths">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="[0].Label" value="fooLabel_1" />
    <input type="text" name="[0].Path" value="fooPath_1" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This removed the tags and also the é character on the input, is it normal? Plus how can i send this one via ajax call i try to do data: JSON.stringify(decodedModel) but it sends a null model to the controller.

Comment: Yes, that's normal. Diacritics are not supported in URLs. If you want to send this in an AJAX request just supply the value to the `data` property. Don't JSON encode it, as it's not JSON. Just `data: model` will work. Note that you don't need to call `decodeURI()` for that to work.